# cyclic reference in Observer pattern implementation in C++

Tags: c++

I tried to work with Observer pattern code which is available in https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/cpp/3

Observer.h

```
#ifndef OBSERVER_H_
#define OBSERVER_H_

namespace my {

class Subject;
//template <class T>
class Observer {
    Subject*model;
    int denom;
    public:
        Observer(Subject*mod, int div);
        virtual void update() = 0;
        virtual ~Observer();
    protected:
        Subject*getSubject();
        int getDivisor();
};

} /* namespace my */

#endif /* OBSERVER_H_ */
```

Observer.cpp

```
#include "Observer.h"
//#include "Subject.h"

namespace my {

Observer::Observer(Subject*mod, int div)
{
    model = mod;
    denom = div;
    // 4. Observers register themselves with the Subject
    model->attach(this);
}

Subject* Observer::getSubject()
{
    return model;
}

int Observer::getDivisor()
{
    return denom;
}

Observer::~Observer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

} /* namespace my */
```

DivObserver.h

```
#ifndef DIVOBSERVER_H_
#define DIVOBSERVER_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "Observer.h"

using namespace std;

namespace my {

class DivObserver : public Observer
{
    public:
        DivObserver(Subject*mod, int div);
        void update();
        virtual ~DivObserver();
};

} /* namespace my */

#endif /* DIVOBSERVER_H_ */
```

DivObserver.cpp

```
#include "DivObserver.h"

namespace my {

DivObserver::DivObserver(Subject*mod, int div): Observer(mod, div){
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

void DivObserver::update()
{
    // 6. "Pull" information of interest
    int v = getSubject()->getVal(), d = getDivisor();
    cout << v << " div " << d << " is " << v / d << '\n';
}

DivObserver::~DivObserver() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

} /* namespace my */
```

Subject.h

```
#ifndef SUBJECT_H_
#define SUBJECT_H_
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

namespace my {
//template <class T>
class Subject {
    vector <class Observer*> views; // 3. Coupled only to "interface"
    int value;
    public:
        Subject();
        virtual ~Subject();

        void attach(Observer*obs);
        void setVal(int val);
        int getVal();
        void notify();
};

} /* namespace my */

#endif /* SUBJECT_H_ */
```

Subject.cpp

```
#include "Subject.h"

namespace my {

Subject::Subject() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

void Subject::attach(Observer*obs)
{
    views.push_back(obs);
}

void Subject::setVal(int val)
{
    value = val;
    notify();
}

int Subject::getVal()
{
    return value;
}

void Subject::notify()
{
  // 5. Publisher broadcasts
  for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
    views[i]->update();
}

Subject::~Subject() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

} /* namespace my */
```

Test.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Subject.h"
#include "DivObserver.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace my;

int main() {
  Subject subj;
  DivObserver divObs1(&subj, 4); // 7. Client configures the number and
  DivObserver divObs2(&subj, 3); //    type of Observers
  subj.setVal(14);
}
```

It complains about cyclic reference. If I insert class Subject; it says ambiguous Subject. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: If you have a compiler error please post an exact message. Also reducing the amount of code could help signifactly

Comment: You should really give the compiler error messages so we can tell exactly what is going wrong. I can see a few things that would cause trouble. You have Subject.h commented out in Observer.cpp, it should not be commented out. You're not including Observer.h in Subject.cpp, it should be included. Also the vector< class Observer*> is syntax I'm not familiar with. I'd stick with the pre declaration like you did for Subject in Observer.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easyest way to resolve this issue is to declare and define observer and observable in one file. It means

Subject.h

```
#ifndef SUBJECT_H_
#define SUBJECT_H_

#include<vector>

namespace my {

class Subject;
//template <class T>
class Observer {
    Subject*model;
    int denom;
    public:
        Observer(Subject*mod, int div);
        virtual void update() = 0;
        virtual ~Observer();
    protected:
        Subject*getSubject();
        int getDivisor();
};

//template <class T>
class Subject {
    std::vector <Observer*> views; // 3. Coupled only to "interface"
    int value;
    public:
        Subject();
        virtual ~Subject();

        void attach(Observer*obs);
        void setVal(int val);
        int getVal();
        void notify();
};


} /* namespace my */

#endif
```

Subject.cpp

```
#include "Subject.h"

namespace my {

DivObserver::DivObserver(Subject*mod, int div): Observer(mod, div){
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

void DivObserver::update()
{
    // 6. "Pull" information of interest
    int v = getSubject()->getVal(), d = getDivisor();
    cout << v << " div " << d << " is " << v / d << '\n';
}

DivObserver::~DivObserver() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

Subject::Subject() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

void Subject::attach(Observer*obs)
{
    views.push_back(obs);
}

void Subject::setVal(int val)
{
    value = val;
    notify();
}

int Subject::getVal()
{
    return value;
}

void Subject::notify()
{
  // 5. Publisher broadcasts
  for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
    views[i]->update();
}

Subject::~Subject() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}


}
```

The harder and the proper way is to declare abstract interfaces

`IObserver` and `IObservable`

That defines general interfaces of Observer and Observable, than we must derive our classes from them.

Observer.h

```
#ifndef __IOBSERVER_H__
#define __IOBSERVER_H__

class IObserver
{
public:
    void update() void = 0;
};

#endif  /* __IOBSERVER_H__ */
```

Observable.h

```
#ifndef __IOBSERVERVABLE_H__
#define __IOBSERVERVABLE_H__

#include "Observer.h"

class IObservable
{
public:
    void attach(IObserver* pObserver) void = 0;
};

#endif  /* __IOBSERVERVABLE_H__ */
```

then derive children

```
class Subject: public IObservable
{
};

class Observer: public IObserver
{
};
```